# Typescript discriminated union type not enforcing required second property, when first property is within enum

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union

I have an enum:

```
export enum Sections {
  Dashboard = "Dashboard",
  Select = "Select",
  Widget = "Widget",
}
```

I want to build a prop for my react components that is a discriminating union type.

```
export type ReduxLocation =
  | {
      path: Sections;
      widget?: never;
    }
  | {
      path: Sections.Widget;
      widget: {
        id: string;
        side?: "left" | "right";
      };
    };
```

Then one of the props of a react component would be of type `ReduxLocation`:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<{ reduxLocation: ReduxLocation }> = () => {
  // return whatever
}
```

The goal is that if passing a `reduxLocation` with a `path` of any of the `Sections`, no other entry is required in the `reduxLocation` object.  However, if `path` is `Sections.Widget`, then the `widget` entry is required.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent 
        reduxLocation={{ 
          path: Sections.Dashboard 
        }} 
      />
      <MyComponent 
        reduxLocation={{ 
          path: Sections.Dashboard, 
          widget: { id: 'id' } // <---- errors as expected
        }} 
      />
      <MyComponent 
        reduxLocation={{ 
          path: Sections.Widget, 
          widget: { id: 'id' } 
        }} 
      />
      <MyComponent 
        reduxLocation={{ 
          path: Sections.Widget 
          // <-------------------------- should error but doesnt
        }} 
      /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the case of the last `MyComponent` above, I am not getting the desired TS error that when using a `path: Sections.Widget`, the `widget` property is then also required.  My guess is because using `path: Sections.Widget` also satisfies the first type in `ReduxLocation`, as `path` is still of type `Maps`.

How can I achieve the desired result, where the above case enforces the correct combination of properties in the prop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `{ path: Sections.Widget }` is totally valid since `Sections.Widget` is assignable to `Sections` which fulfills the constraints of the first union element.

You would want to exclude `Sections.Widget` from the `path` of the first element. That way, the union can be propertly discriminated since each `Section` is only assignable to one union element.

```
export type ReduxLocation =
  | {
      path: Exclude<Sections, Sections.Widget>;
      widget?: never;
    }
  | {
      path: Sections.Widget;
      widget: {
        id: string;
        side?: "left" | "right";
      };
    };
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQCUCmBDAxsgZnGCJAIjkx2NFDQA9ZEk0A7AVyIGU0cwYmBnJAG9QSJABEMfABYAjGBjgATJAF4SE6XIWLiAGhFJOAGy7I1xY6b0GA6mEUBzNGZJ3Hz6yAC%20VELXrICACeUGioaIosNAAyMFgYCDxMqgYAPkIGoqJQCVIAXEgAojRYRiyKaAA8nNy8fLqGpkl8AHRuTggAfADcmVkA7vYdAPwFTGgAbmhwvSBZSD5zSOnCS-M5CPmNtfxtQ86z86KD7ggFq0dZ9gV8CHBgTA6Hl0h89mijJCa4CMTLJPcHFJfs95l5QQtZqAsHVkABZIIAYUIsHGTDO4WwCBaADFEZVBEgyJEYnEEkkCugSbF4oleAtOqokAAKACUqkZFyQAHpuUTnCw4Ml%20lIEpNpqBFtDYUgAIJQKBMtkcjJLMgIQXJZl9SqKMATTp9USVBHI6C8ZjIYlRGnk3gqQSEjZbGp03YaWTyJQLLw8w1rLImpEoi3o-nUsluh1O3IFV3NPanBonDrnJDXJAAcnsmYWPr9RqQQbNqMt4ZtkaS0aQzrjTTqiY6%20e5-vmlW5eoNBlZsy8QA)